Solutions, in $X$ of $(I + AX)B(I + XA) = C$
Consider the matrix equation
$$
(I + AX)B(I+ XA) = C,
$$
where $X$ is the unknown real, symmetric, positive semidefinite matrix, and $A, B,C$ are known, real symmetric, positive semidefinite matrices. Further we know $B \preceq C$.
Is there a way to solve this and to characterize the set of solutions? I understand in general there seems there could be many or no solutions, but is there any way to find an explicit solution? If not, what is known about this kind of equation?
Obviously, we can look at the scalar case, for $a >0, c \geq b > 0$, we obtain
$$
x = \frac{1}{a} (\sqrt{c/b} - 1).
$$

if you call $I +AX=D$ and can solve  $DBD^T =C$ for $D$, you are practically there

It's very complicate to solve the equation. Indeed, if $A$, $B$ or $C$ are not strictly positive definite matrix (in order words, there exists an eigenvalue equal to zero), the equation may have infinite solutions or zero solutions. Same as in the scalar case where $a,b$ or $c$ are not strictly positive. Otherwise, if all these 3 matrices are positive definite, it's a piece of cake.

What does $B\preceq C$ mean? What is the partial order being used here?

Under the assumptions that $A\succeq0$ and $C\succeq B\succeq0$, we can give an iterative algorithm that determines the solvability of the equation and obtains a solution when it is solvable.
In each new iteration, we first check whether the matrices are $1\times1$. If so, the equation is solvable if and only if $B=C$ (for which $X=0$ is a solution) or $A>0$ and $C>B>0$ (with $X=\frac{1}{A}\sqrt{\frac{C}{B}}$ as a solution).
Otherwise, we check whether $A$ and $B$ are both positive definite. If so, we may stop and a solution is given by formula $(3)$ in my other answer (i.e., $X=L^{-T}(L^TA^{-1}CA^{-1}L)^{1/2}L^{-1}-A^{-1}$ when $B=LL^T$).
If both cases above fail to hold, i.e., if the matrices are $2\times2$ or larger and at least one of $A$ or $B$ is singular, rewrite the equation as
$$
AXB+BXA+AXBXA=C-B.\tag{1}
$$
Let $\Pi_1$ be the orthogonal projection onto the range of $A$ and $\Pi_2=I-\Pi_1$ be the orthogonal projection onto $\ker(A)$. Since $\Pi_2A=A\Pi_2=0$, if $(1)$ is solvable, we must have
$$
\Pi_2(C-B)\Pi_2=0\tag{2}
$$
If this necessary condition is not satisfied, we stop immediately and conclude that the equation is not solvable. Otherwise, we continue. Since $(2)$ holds and $C-B$ is positive semidefinite, we must also have $\Pi_1(C-B)\Pi_2=0$. Hence $(1)$ boils down to the system of equations
\begin{cases}
\Pi_1(AXB+BXA+AXBXA)\Pi_1=\Pi_1(C-B)\Pi_1,\\
\Pi_1(AXB+BXA+AXBXA)\Pi_2=\Pi_1(C-B)\Pi_2=0.\\
\end{cases}
That is,
\begin{align}
&AXB\Pi_1+\Pi_1BXA+AXBXA=\Pi_1(C-B)\Pi_1,\tag{3}\\
&\Pi_1XB\Pi_2=0.\tag{4}\\
\end{align}
By a change of orthonormal basis, we may assume that
$$
A=\pmatrix{A_1&0\\ 0&0},\quad
B=\pmatrix{B_1&B_2\\ B_2^T&B_3},\quad
C=\pmatrix{C_1&C_2\\ C_2^T&C_3},\quad
X=\pmatrix{X_1&X_2\\ X_2^T&X_3},\quad
$$
where $A_1\succ0$ and it has the same size as $B_1,C_1$ and $X_1$. Condition $(2)$ simply means that $B_3=C_3$ (and by implication, $B_2=C_2$, because $C\succeq B$), while equation $(4)$ can be rewritten as
$$
X_1B_2+X_2B_3=0.\tag{4'}
$$
Now, by a straightforward computation,
\begin{align*}
\Pi_1XBX\Pi_1
&=\Pi_1XB\Pi_1X\Pi_1\\
&=(\Pi_1X)(B\Pi_1)(\Pi_1X\Pi_1)\\
&=\pmatrix{X_1&X_2\\ 0&0}\pmatrix{B_1&0\\ B_2^T&0}\pmatrix{X_1&0\\ 0&0}\\
&=\pmatrix{(X_1B_1+X_2B_2^T)X_1&0\\ 0&0}.\\
\end{align*}
Therefore $(3)$ is equivalent to
$$
A_1(X_1B_1+X_2B_2^T)+(B_1X_1+B_2X_2^T)A_1+A_1(X_1B_1+X_2B_2^T)X_1A_1=C_1-B_1.
$$
Since $B$ is positive semidefinite, we may write $B_2=B_1MB_3$ for some matrix $M$. Therefore, by $(4')$,
\begin{align*}
X_1B_1+X_2B_2^T
&=X_1B_1+X_2B_3M^TB_1\\
&=X_1B_1-X_1B_2M^TB_1\\
&=X_1B_1-X_1B_1MB_3M^TB_1\\
&=X_1(B_1-B_1MB_3M^TB_1)\\
&=X_1(B_1-B_1MB_3B_3^+B_3M^TB_1)\\
&=X_1(B_1-B_2B_3^+B_2^T)\\
&=X_1B'.
\end{align*}
where $B'=B_1-B_2B_3^+B_2^T$ denotes the (generalised) Schur complement of $B_3$ in $B$. Similarly,
\begin{align*}
(X_1B_1+X_2B_2^T)X_1
&=X_1B_1X_1-X_2B_3X_2^T\\
&=X_1B_1X_1-X_2B_3B_3^+B_3X_2^T\\
&=X_1B_1X_1-X_1B_2B_3^+B_2^TX_1\\
&=X_1B'X_1.
\end{align*}
It follows that equation $(3)$ can be further rewritten as
$$
A_1X_1B'+B'X_1A_1+A_1X_1B'X_1A_1=C'-B'\tag{3'}
$$
where $C'=C_1-B_1+B'$.
At this point, equation $(1)$ is solvable if and only if $(3'),(4')$ are solvable by some positive semidefinite $X$.
Now, given any $X_1\succeq0$, equation $(4')$ can always be solved by $X_2=-X_1B_1M$. Since equation $(3')$ involves only $X_1$, if it is solvable, then
$$
X=\pmatrix{X_1&-X_1B_1M\\ -M^TB_1X_1^T&cI}\tag{5}
$$
is a positive semidefinite solution to our problem when $c>0$ is sufficiently large. Therefore, the solvability of equation $(1)$ is equivalent to the validity of condition $(2)$ and the solvability of $(3')$. However, as $C\succeq B\succeq0$, we have $C'\succeq B'\succeq0$. Therefore $(3')$ assumes the same form as $(1)$, but the sizes of the matrices are smaller and the new matrix (namely, $A_1$) that takes the role of $A$ is positive definite.
So, we begin our next iteration with $A_1,B',C',X_1$ taking the roles of $A,B,C,X$, and proceed recursively. Since the sizes of the matrices are reduced in each iteration, the algorithm will terminate in finite steps. If, in some iteration other than the first, a solution $X_1$ to the downsized equation $(3')$ is found, we need to backtrack and construct a solution for the previous iterations by applying $(5)$ iteratively.

Here is a partial answer. We consider the special case where $A,B$ and $C$ are positive definite. Write $B=LL^T$ for some square matrix $L$ (e.g. one may take $L$ as either $B^{1/2}$ or the Cholesky factor of $B$). When the equation is solvable, we must have
$$
(I+AX)L=C^{1/2}Q
$$
for some orthogonal matrix $Q$. Hence
$$
X=A^{-1}C^{1/2}QL^{-1}-A^{-1}.\tag{1}
$$
Therefore $X+A^{-1}=A^{-1}C^{1/2}QL^{-1}$ is positive definite and so is
$$
P=L^T(X+A^{-1})L=L^TA^{-1}C^{1/2}Q.\tag{2}
$$
It follows that
$$
P=(LA^{-1}CA^{-1}L^T)^{1/2}.
$$
Consequently, from $(2)$ and $(1)$, we must have
$$
X=L^{-T}(L^TA^{-1}CA^{-1}L)^{1/2}L^{-1}-A^{-1}\tag{3}
$$
where $L^{-T}$ means $(L^{-1})^T$.
It is straightforward to verify that this $X$ is symmetric and it satisfies $(I+AX)B(I+XA)=C$. Note that the expression $(3)$ does not depend on how the factor $L$ in the decomposition $B=LL^T$ is chosen.
So, when $A,B$ and $C$ are positive definite, the equation is solvable if and only if the $X$ in $(3)$ is positive semidefinite. When $X$ is indeed PSD, it is the unique solution to the equation.
In general, if $B$ and $C$ are unrelated, $X$ may not be positive semidefinite. Conversely, when $A\succ0,\,X\succeq0$ and $B\succ0$ are chosen arbitrarily, $C=(I+AX)B(I+XA)$ is not always $\succeq B$. This is a stark contrast to the scalar case, in which (assuming that $A>0$) the equation is solvable by some $X\ge0$ if and only if $C\ge B$.
However, when $C\succeq B$, we have
\begin{align*}
L^TA^{-1}CA^{-1}L
\succeq L^TA^{-1}BA^{-1}L
= L^TA^{-1}LL^TA^{-1}L
= (L^TA^{-1}L)^2.
\end{align*}
Therefore the $X$ in $(3)$ is guaranteed to be positive semidefinite.
